# What is the difference between -moz-transform and -moz-transform-origin?

Tags: css, firefox, css-transforms

What is the difference between [-moz-transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-transform) and [-moz-transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/-moz-transform-origin) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-moz-transform` gives the transformation, `-moz-transform-origin` says what point within the element is (0, 0) when applying it.

So if you have:

```
-moz-transform: rotate(90);
-moz-transform-origin: center;
```

Then you get a 90-degree rotation around the center of the element.